# I cant make file with python on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

my bot gives error when this happens in my code:

```py
with open(f"tickets/{num}.txt","w+"):
```

after that it gives this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/main.py", line 231, in on_reaction_add
    with open(f"tickets/{num}.txt","w+") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tickets/001.txt'
```

it works on replit but not on heroku. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the directory `tickets/` exists on the Heroku machine. You can do this by running a console on the app's dashboard. Run bash, and then use `$ mkdir tickets` to create it.

Comment: it only works on bash console and it doesnt the do the thing I want on the worker

Comment: @PNourian Could you clarify what you mean by that? You can run `main.py` successfully in bash?